# %--% operator in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I came across the following code in “R for Data Science”. What does %--% operator do here.

```
library(lubridate)    
next_year <- today() + years(1)
(today() %--% next_year) / ddays(1)
#> [1] 365
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It calls `interval(start, end)` wherein `start` is the left hand side of the operation and `end` is the right hand side. See `?interval`.

Comment: Using R for several years, the most frustrating thing for me is the (lack of) documentation and examples in the help files. `%--%` is shown in the lubridate `interval` function, but there is no example code and no discussion. Found example code in the description for the `timespan` function, but no discussion. Many similar cases exist ESPECIALLY in base functions.

Comment: What @teunbrand said is what the documentation for `interval` needs to say for this operator.

Comment: All I did was to print out the function, said what expression it calls en refer to the documentation. I've never used the operator once in my life (until today, that is). But yeah the documentation isn't great.